# Concatenating buffer when the sending is too fast in a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, winsock2

I have a socket server receiving XML files each 500ms and sometimes it goes wrong concatenating more than 1 file as only one file.

```
do
{
    char* buf = (char*)MALLOCZ(IP_BUF_SZ);
    chrs_read = recv(sockfd, buf, IP_BUF_SZ, 0);

    if (chrs_read > 0)
        sBuffer.append(buf, chrs_read);

    FREE(buf);
    buf = NULL;
}
while (chrs_read > 0);
```

So, sometime `chrs_read` doesn't return me `-1` to stop the receiving and save the file to start a new receiving.
Do I forget some configuration in the socket - it's async and non-blocking by default - and I supposed to keep using this way?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Not to clear on the problem.  Are you saying the recv blocks?  If so, you can set flags on the NOWAIT flag and check the result.  recv can also return 0 if the other side closes the socket,  are you covering that case? As an aside, move the malloc and free outside of your do/while.

Comment: Are you sending several files in the same TCP stream? (Bad idea, unless you insert your own "end of file" marker in the stream.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all files are sent through the same connection, without having a delimiter between them. When the files are sent often, and there is some latency in the network, you can't know where a file ends and a new one begins.

Solutions:

- Insert a delimiter between the files, such that you can close the file when you receive the delimiter, and open a new one. Note that the delimiter may be received anywhere inside of `buf`, or it could even, if the delimiter is longer than one byte, be received partially in one `recv` call, and the rest follows in the next `recv` call.
- On the sending end, close the connection after sending the file and open a new one for the new file.